# Рыцарский крест — с прописной буквы?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия

Из комментария: «...грудь полковника украшал Рыцарский крест с дубовыми листьями...»
Награда — Рыцарский крест. С прописной буквы?

Comment: Желательно привести полное предложение (или контекст). Правильность названия вызывает сомнение.

Comment: «...грудь полковника украшал Рыцарский крест с дубовыми листьями...»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что здесь нужно ориентироваться вот на это правило.

> Названия орденов, медалей, наград, знаков отличия, не сочетающиеся синтаксически с родовым наименованием, заключаются в кавычки и в них пишутся с прописной буквы первое слово и собственные имена, напр.: *орден «Мать-героиня», орден «За заслуги перед Отечеством»*...
> Все прочие названия наград и знаков отличия кавычками не выделяются и в них пишется с прописной буквы первое слово (кроме слов *орден, медаль*) и собственные имена, напр.: *орден Дружбы, орден Отечественной войны I степени, орден Почетного легиона* (Франция), *орден Андрея Первозванного, орден Святого Георгия, медаль Материнства, **Георгиевский крест**; Государственная премия, Нобелевская премия.*

Он сделал ещё одну попытку доказать свою правоту и получил высший орден Империи ― **Рыцарский крест с дубовыми листьями**. [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, часть 3 (1960)]

[Названия орденов, медалей, наград, знаков отличия](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=91#pp91) (Лопатин)
[Названия орденов и медалей](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=172#pp172) (Розенталь)